# React native await not working in pressed function

Tags: react-native, redux, async-await

I have an async function that uses redux and it calls an API and returns the response from the server:

```
function xyz() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { user: { token } } = getState();
    return axios.get(API_URL, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'jwt': token
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.data);
        return response.data.data;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error.message);
      });
  };
}
```

The mapDispatchToProps function is defined as it follows:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    xyz: () => {
      dispatch(actions.xyz());
    }
  };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Container);
```

I'm trying to call the function xyz from the following function:

```
  abc = async () => {
    const { xyz } = this.props;
    const result = await xyz();
    console.log(result);
  }
```

which is triggered when a button is pressed:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPressOut={this.abc}>
```

I see that the console.log into the function abc prints undefined, while the console.log(result.data.data) into xyz prints the expected result. Where am I wrong?

### Solution

The error was in the mapDispatchToProps function, which was missing the return. Here it is the correct implementation:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    xyz: () => {
      return dispatch(actions.xyz());
    }
  };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Container);
```

Comment: Are you sure the await xyz() call is returning undefined? Seems like it should return a promise (axios.get).

Comment: Yes, sure. It's really very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, xyz() should return a promise. Double check that the dispatch and getState arguments are getting passed correctly. You'll also need to [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the returned axios.get promise. For example:

```
abc = async () => {
  const { xyz } = this.props;
  const result = await xyz();
  const results = await result(); 
  console.log(results);
}
```

Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@jasonjlock/great-scone) with a working example.

Comment: Thank you, finally I managed to make it work! I will update the post adding the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you mean when you say the `console.log` in xyz prints the expected result, are you speaking about the `error.message` in your `catch`?  Also, the reason you may be receiving `undefined` is because `function xyz` is not **Async** but rather it returns an async function, thus you should make xyz **async** such as:

```
function async xyz () {
 // Rest of code
}
```

For more you can read [here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that in .then() the console.log was missing. I just edited the question to make it clear. Anyway I tried to add the keyword async to the function xyz and I get this error: "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection. Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."